# How to merge tables in MySQL, although not just an outright merge?

Tags: mysql, join, merge

I have three tables titled 'artist', 'album', and 'track' in MySQL, each containing information pertaining to my music library. 'artist' has the name of 4 artists, 'album' has the titles of 5 albums from those artists, and 'track' has the name of all tracks on said albums. I would like to combine the tables so the each track name has beside it the correct album title and artist name. Here are my tables:

## artist

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| artist_id | artist_name     |
+-----------+-----------------+
|         1 | Kacey Musgraves |
|         2 | The Lone Bellow |
|         3 | Ed Sheeran      |
|         4 | The Civil Wars  |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

## album

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
| artist_id | album_id | album_name            |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
|         1 |        1 | Pageant Material      |
|         2 |        1 | Then Came the Morning |
|         3 |        1 | +                     |
|         3 |        2 | x                     |
|         4 |        1 | The Civil Wars        |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

## track

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+------------+
| artist_id | album_id | track_id | track_name                    | track_time |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+------------+
|         1 |        1 |        1 | Makin' Music for Money        |       2.97 |
|         1 |        1 |        2 | Dime Store Cowgirl            |       3.58 |
|         1 |        1 |        3 | Late to the Party             |       3.63 |
|         1 |        1 |        4 | Pageant Material              |       3.90 |
|         1 |        1 |        5 | This Town                     |       2.95 |
|         1 |        1 |        6 | Biscuits                      |       3.28 |
|         1 |        1 |        7 | Somebody to Love              |       3.22 |
|         1 |        1 |        8 | Miserable                     |       3.00 |
|         1 |        1 |        9 | Die Fun                       |       3.47 |
|         1 |        1 |       10 | Family is Family              |       2.53 |
|         1 |        1 |       11 | Good Ol' Boys Club            |       3.27 |
|         1 |        1 |       12 | Cup of Tea                    |       2.67 |
|         1 |        1 |       13 | Fine                          |       7.88 |
|         2 |        1 |        1 | Then Came the Morning         |       4.01 |
|         2 |        1 |        2 | Fake Roses                    |       3.57 |
|         2 |        1 |        3 | Marietta                      |       3.57 |
|         2 |        1 |        4 | Take My Love                  |       3.25 |
|         2 |        1 |        5 | Call to War                   |       3.47 |
|         2 |        1 |        6 | Watch Over Us                 |       3.57 |
|         2 |        1 |        7 | Diners                        |       4.40 |
|         2 |        1 |        8 | Heaven Don't Call Me Home     |       2.60 |
|         2 |        1 |        9 | If You Don't Love Me          |       3.23 |
|         2 |        1 |       10 | Telluride                     |       4.28 |
|         2 |        1 |       11 | To the Woods                  |       2.00 |
|         2 |        1 |       12 | Cold As It Is                 |       2.93 |
|         2 |        1 |       13 | I Let You Go                  |       3.42 |
|         3 |        1 |        1 | The A Team                    |       4.66 |
|         3 |        1 |        2 | Drunk                         |       4.32 |
|         3 |        1 |        3 | U.N.I.                        |       3.82 |
|         3 |        1 |        4 | Grade 8                       |       3.00 |
|         3 |        1 |        5 | Wake Me Up                    |       3.83 |
|         3 |        1 |        6 | Small Bump                    |       4.32 |
|         3 |        1 |        7 | This                          |       3.27 |
|         3 |        1 |        8 | The City                      |       3.90 |
|         3 |        1 |        9 | Lego House                    |       3.08 |
|         3 |        1 |       10 | You Need Me, I Don't Need You |       3.67 |
|         3 |        1 |       11 | Kiss Me                       |       4.68 |
|         3 |        1 |       12 | Give Me Love                  |       8.77 |
|         3 |        2 |        1 | One                           |       4.22 |
|         3 |        2 |        2 | I'm A Mess                    |       4.08 |
|         3 |        2 |        3 | Sing                          |       3.92 |
|         3 |        2 |        4 | Don't                         |       3.67 |
|         3 |        2 |        5 | Nina                          |       3.77 |
|         3 |        2 |        6 | Photograph                    |       4.32 |
|         3 |        2 |        7 | Bloodstream                   |       5.00 |
|         3 |        2 |        8 | Tenerife Sea                  |       4.02 |
|         3 |        2 |        9 | Runaway                       |       3.42 |
|         3 |        2 |       10 | The Man                       |       4.17 |
|         3 |        2 |       11 | Thinking Out Loud             |       4.70 |
|         3 |        2 |       12 | Afire Love                    |       5.23 |
|         3 |        2 |       13 | Take It BAck                  |       3.47 |
|         3 |        2 |       14 | Shirtsleeves                  |       3.17 |
|         3 |        2 |       15 | Even My Dad Does Sometimes    |       3.82 |
|         3 |        2 |       16 | I See Fire                    |       4.98 |
|         4 |        1 |        1 | The One That Got Away         |       3.55 |
|         4 |        1 |        2 | I Had Me a Girl               |       3.75 |
|         4 |        1 |        3 | Same Old Same Old             |       3.80 |
|         4 |        1 |        4 | Dust to Dust                  |       3.83 |
|         4 |        1 |        5 | Eavesdrop                     |       3.58 |
|         4 |        1 |        6 | Devil's Backbone              |       2.48 |
|         4 |        1 |        7 | From This Valley              |       3.55 |
|         4 |        1 |        8 | Tell Mama                     |       3.80 |
|         4 |        1 |        9 | Oh Henry                      |       3.55 |
|         4 |        1 |       10 | Disarm                        |       4.70 |
|         4 |        1 |       11 | Sacred Heart                  |       3.32 |
|         4 |        1 |       12 | D'Arline                      |       3.10 |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+------------+
```

In 'track' each number under artist_id corresponds to the same numbered entry in 'artist', and the same goes for album_id and 'album'. Basically, I want to create a new table with every track in 'track', along with its respective album and artist.Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` in your `SELECT` query, like,
`select * from track_name 
join artist_name on track_name.artist_id = artist_name.artist_id 
join album_name on track_name.album_id = album_name.album_id;`

Now if you want this in new table you can `insert` this records in that table, or better if you want to run above query multiple time then you can create a `VIEW`.
[MySQL Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a very basic join

```
select * 
  from track_name
  join artist_name using (artist_id)
  join album_name using (album_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this query by hoping there would be columns **album_id** and **artist_id** in the respective tables.

I also suggest you to change the column name track_name so to avoid conflict between table name and column name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `track_name` t1
LEFT JOIN `artist_name` a1 ON t1.`artist_id`=a1.`artist_id`
LEFT JOIN `album_name` a2 ON t1.`album_name`=a2.`album_name`
GROUP BY t1.`track_name`;
```